# assigning a key name to my combo box style

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I modified a combobox style and the style is listed below. It works fine, however, the style applies to all comboboxes in my project. In other words, when I pull a combobox from the toolbox, it is automatically styled. What I'd like to do is only style certain comboboxes with the style - not all. Of course I would have to apply the style to each control using a key name. My question is, how can the style be modified so I can refer to it by a key name "myComboBox". Thanks for your help.

STYLE IN MY RESOURCE DICTIONARY:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
                x:Name="Border" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                CornerRadius="0"
                Background="Black" 
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0" />
        <Border 
                Grid.Column="0"
                CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" 
                Margin="1" 
                Background="Black" 
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" />
        <Path 
              x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="#404040"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#808080" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="#888888" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                            Name="ToggleButton" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="1,0,11,0" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                            Style="{x:Null}" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Margin="1,0,11,0"
                            Focusable="True" 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
                            Name="Popup"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                            Focusable="False"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                                  Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    BorderBrush="#888888"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                                Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBoxItem -->

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a `x:Key` like that it create an [implicit style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating#relationship-of-the-targettype-property-and-the-xkey-attribute). What you are wanting is an explicit style. 
What you need to do is change this line

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
```

to be

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
```

In addition you have an implicit style on ComboBoxItem as well. You will want to change this:

to be:

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
```

Finally you will want to set your ComboBoxItem style to be the item style for your ComboBox.
Add this to the ComboBox style.

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource myComboBoxItem}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks to all who chimed in. This seemed to be the most complete answer and Is working now.

Comment: @namg_engr: What's the difference between this answer and mine?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `Style` a unique `x:Key`:

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
```

You can then apply it to a `ComboBox` using the `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource myComboBoxStyle}">        
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I added the style and unique key as one line in the resource dictionary, however, the style still applies to all combo box controls in the project even when the style is not applied.

Comment: One line? All you need to do is to change the key from ”{x:Type ComboBoxItem}” to for example ”myComboBoxStyle”.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the key you're using.
This:
    x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
Change that to some other string that doesn't involve any curly braces or x:type.